# can not understand std::thread usage

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I am reading documents about c++11 multi-threads, and met this example for `std::thread`.

Code:

```
void thread_task(int n) {
  ...
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::thread threads[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(thread_task, i + 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand `threads[i] = std::thread(thread_task, i + 1);`. Is the `std::thread` a static function call, and returns a reference for std::thread object? Sounds inconceivable, but seems to be what the code say.

Because I would write it like this:

```
std::thread *threads[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    threads[i] = new std::thread(thread_task, i + 1);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: inconvincible?  A neologism or a brain stumble on inconceivable?

Comment: `std::thread` is a class, and calling a class by parentheses mostly calls its constructor. The `new` creates memory on the heap that you have to manage manually (call `delete` yourself). Omitting the `new` means the object is created on the stack and deleted if you leave the scope.

Comment: Note that the code presented is incomplete; before `main` returns it must call `join` on each of the thread objects.

Comment: @Duck Sorry for bad English. I mean inconceivable.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, I omit something.

Comment: @lulyon - I'm sorry, I didn't realize English might not be your first language.  I wasn't berating you, I just find things like that kind of funny and sometimes accidentally creative uses of language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's go through exactly what is happening:

```
std::thread threads[5];
```

This creates an array of 5 `std::thread` objects, which are default constructed. Currently they represent "not a thread" as this is the state default construction leaves them in.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    threads[i] = std::thread(thread_task, i + 1);
}
```

This uses the move form of `operator=`. Because threads are not copyable, only moveable, `thread& operator=(thread&& t)` is defined while `thread& operator=(const thread& t)` is not. This assigns the thread object in `threads[i]` to the newly constructed `std::thread(thread_task, i + 1);`.

There is no reason to use an array of pointers here. It adds nothing but the possibility for memory leaks.

Comment: Wording: I'd change "creates an array of 5 threads" to "creates an array of 5 `std::thread` objects" and "This assigns the thread object in ..." should be the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the `std::thread` a static function call, and returns a reference for `std::thread` object?

No, it's creating a temporary thread object; just as `int(42)` creates a temporary integer. The assignment moves that into the array, since threads are movable and temporaries can be moved from.

> Because I would write it like this:

You're introducing dynamic allocation, an extra level of indirection, and memory leaks (unless you also add code to delete them when you're finished) for no good reason.

Answer (score 2):

The [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) of `std::thread` creates an instance that does *not* represent a thread. The assignment is a [move-assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D), since copies are also not allowed. It moves the real instance created by `std::thread(thread_task, i + 1);` into the array.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
std::thread(thread_task, i + 1)
```

is a call to the std::thread constructor, which creates a new thread object and passes it a pointer to the thread_task function, which itself is called with i+1 as parameter.

The assignment is a move assignment (because the right hand side refers to an anonymous object), not a copy assignment. Note that the std::thread copy constructor and copy assignment operator are deleted.

This is actually a cleaner way than using pointers, because the std::thread objects will be destructed automatically when the threads array goes out of scope.